# Can python load definitions from a C header file?

Tags: python, ctypes, header-files

I'm writing a python Wrapper around a C API. I have an extensive API description and right now I'm struggling with the implementation of enums defined in the header file.

Let's assume i have a C API function inside `myAPI.dll`, that accepts an enum as argument like:

```
void SomeFunction(SomeEnum data)
```

From the header file, I can see that `SomeEnum` looks like:

```
enum SomeEnum{
    SomeValue = 1,
    SomeOtherValue = 2,
    SomeVeryStupidValue = -1
};
```

In python, I load the `.dll` like:

```
myAPI = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('myAPI.dll')
```

now I would like to be able to call:

```
myAPI.SomeFunction(SomeValue)
```

I know, that I could define `SomeValue` in python, but it would be convenient to load its definition directly from the header file or have it directly as an attribute of `myAPI`. Is this possible?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48835308/import-c-enum-into-python-without-including-full-header) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942020/how-to-import-constants-from-h-file-into-python-module) help?

Comment: @rafaelc yes it does. It actually means, that it seems to be okay to parse the header file to define python globals.

Comment: How about a specific example? There are lots of unknowns here (*OS*, compiler, and so on). [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible.  I wrote a tool years ago to scan a file for C++ `enum` syntax using [pyparsing](https://pypi.org/project/pyparsing/).  It's now a [pyparsing example](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/cpp_enum_parser.py) that I've reproduced here in case the link changes.  As you can see the file doesn't have to even be entirely valid C++.  It defines the `enum` grammar and scans the file for text matching the grammar, generating Python variables.

```
#
# cpp_enum_parser.py
#
# Posted by Mark Tolonen on comp.lang.python in August, 2009,
# Used with permission.
#
# Parser that scans through C or C++ code for enum definitions, and
# generates corresponding Python constant definitions.
#
#

from pyparsing import *

# sample string with enums and other stuff
sample = """
    stuff before
    enum hello {
        Zero,
        One,
        Two,
        Three,
        Five=5,
        Six,
        Ten=10
        };
    in the middle
    enum blah
        {
        alpha,
        beta,
        gamma = 10 ,
        zeta = 50
        };
    at the end
    """

# syntax we don't want to see in the final parse tree
LBRACE, RBRACE, EQ, COMMA = map(Suppress, "{}=,")
_enum = Suppress("enum")
identifier = Word(alphas, alphanums + "_")
integer = Word(nums)
enumValue = Group(identifier("name") + Optional(EQ + integer("value")))
enumList = Group(enumValue + ZeroOrMore(COMMA + enumValue))
enum = _enum + identifier("enum") + LBRACE + enumList("names") + RBRACE

# find instances of enums ignoring other syntax
for item, start, stop in enum.scanString(sample):
    id = 0
    for entry in item.names:
        if entry.value != "":
            id = int(entry.value)
        print("%s_%s = %d" % (item.enum.upper(), entry.name.upper(), id))
        id += 1
```

Output:

```
HELLO_ZERO = 0
HELLO_ONE = 1
HELLO_TWO = 2
HELLO_THREE = 3
HELLO_FIVE = 5
HELLO_SIX = 6
HELLO_TEN = 10
BLAH_ALPHA = 0
BLAH_BETA = 1
BLAH_GAMMA = 10
BLAH_ZETA = 50
```

Answer (score 5):

Adapting the code from Mark Tolonen to create actual Python Enums:

```
# import the dependencies
from enum import EnumMeta, IntEnum
from pyparsing import Group, Optional, Suppress, Word, ZeroOrMore
from pyparsing import alphas, alphanums, nums
```

The first step is to create a new `EnumMeta` type (note that this is one of the times [when subclassing `EnumMeta` is a good idea)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43730305/208880):

```
CPPEnum = None
class CPPEnumType(EnumMeta):
    #
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(metacls, clsname, bases, **kwds):
        # return a standard dictionary for the initial processing
        return {}
    #
    def __init__(clsname, *args , **kwds):
        super(CPPEnumType, clsname).__init__(*args)
    #
    def __new__(metacls, clsname, bases, clsdict, **kwds):
        if CPPEnum is None:
            # first time through, ignore the rest
            enum_dict = super(CPPEnumType, metacls).__prepare__(
                    clsname, bases, **kwds
                    )
            enum_dict.update(clsdict)
            return super(CPPEnumType, metacls).__new__(
                    metacls, clsname, bases, enum_dict, **kwds,
                    )
        members = []
        #
        # remove _file and _name using `pop()` as they will
        # cause problems in EnumMeta
        try:
            file = clsdict.pop('_file')
        except KeyError:
            raise TypeError('_file not specified')
        cpp_enum_name = clsdict.pop('_name', clsname.lower())
        with open(file) as fh:
            file_contents = fh.read()
        #
        # syntax we don't want to see in the final parse tree
        LBRACE, RBRACE, EQ, COMMA = map(Suppress, "{}=,")
        _enum = Suppress("enum")
        identifier = Word(alphas, alphanums + "_")
        integer = Word(nums)
        enumValue = Group(identifier("name") + Optional(EQ + integer("value")))
        enumList = Group(enumValue + ZeroOrMore(COMMA + enumValue))
        enum = _enum + identifier("enum") + LBRACE + enumList("names") + RBRACE
        #
        # find the cpp_enum_name ignoring other syntax and other enums
        for item, start, stop in enum.scanString(file_contents):
            if item.enum != cpp_enum_name:
                continue
            id = 0
            for entry in item.names:
                if entry.value != "":
                    id = int(entry.value)
                members.append((entry.name.upper(), id))
                id += 1
        #
        # get the real EnumDict
        enum_dict = super(CPPEnumType, metacls).__prepare__(clsname, bases, **kwds)
        # transfer the original dict content, names starting with '_' first
        items = list(clsdict.items())
        items.sort(key=lambda p: (0 if p[0][0] == '_' else 1, p))
        for name, value in items:
            enum_dict[name] = value
        # add the members
        for name, value in members:
            enum_dict[name] = value
        return super(CPPEnumType, metacls).__new__(
                metacls, clsname, bases, enum_dict, **kwds,
                )
```

Once the new type is created, we can create the new base class:

```
class CPPEnum(IntEnum, metaclass=CPPEnumType):
    pass
```

Once you have the new `CPPEnum` base class, using it is as simple as:

```
class Hello(CPPEnum):
    _file = 'some_header.h'

class Blah(CPPEnum):
    _file = 'some_header.h'
    _name = 'blah'              # in case the name in the file is not the lower-cased
                                # version of the Enum class name (so not needed in
                                # in this case)
```

And in use:

```
>>> list(Hello)
[
    <Hello.ZERO: 0>, <Hello.ONE: 1>, <Hello.TWO: 2>, <Hello.THREE: 3>,
    <Hello.FIVE: 5>, <Hello.SIX: 6>, <Hello.TEN: 10>,
    ]
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Thanks. That answer adds a lot of value! I'm unsure if I should change my accepted answer to this one, because my initial question is basically answered already. But your answer is highly appreciated!

Comment: @Dschoni: I'm glad it's useful!