# python mapping with syntax-checkable keys

Tags: python, enums, mapping

I need to create a mapping of keys (strings, all suitable python identifiers) to values in python (3.9).
All keys and values are constant and known at creation time and i want to make sure, that every single key has an associated value.

**1. dict**

The first idea that comes to mind for this would be using a dictionary, which comes with the big problem that keys (in my case) would be strings.

That means i have to retype the key each time a value is accessed manually in a string literal, so IDEs and type checkers can't spot typos, suggest key names in autocomplete and i can't use their utility functions to rename or find usages of a key.

**1.5 dict with constant variable keys**

the naive solution for this would be to create a constant for each key or an enum, which i don't think is a good solution. Not only is at least one name-lookup added to each access, it also means that the key definition and the value assignment are separated, which can lead to keys that don't have a value assigned to them.

**2. enum**

This leads to the idea to skip the dict and use an enum to associate the keys directly with the values. Enums are conveniently supported by syntax-checkers, auto completion an the likes, as they support both attribute reference via "dot-notation" and subscriptions via "[]".

However an enum has the big disadvantage that it requires all keys/Enum-Members to have unique values and keys violating this rule will automatically be converted to aliases which makes outputs very confusing.

I already thought about copying the Enum-Code and removing the unwanted bits, but this seems to be a lot of effort for such a basic problem.

**question:**

So basically, what i'm looking for is a pythonic, neat and concise way to define a (potentially immutable) mapping from string keys to arbitrary values which supports the following:

- iterable (over keys)
- keys with identical values don't interfere with each other
- keys are required to have an associated value
- keys are considered by syntax-checkers, auto-completion, refactorings, etc.

The preferred way of using it would be to define it in a python source file but it would be a nice bonus, if the solution supported easy means to write the data to a text file (json format, or ini or similar) and to create a new instance from such a file.

How would you do that and why would you choose a specific solution?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, I would use `aenum`<sup>1</sup>, which has a `noalias` setting (so duplicate values can exist with distinct names):

```
from aenum import NoAliasEnum

class Unqiue(NoAliasEnum):
    first = 1
    one = 1
```

and in use:

```
>>> Unique.first
<Unique.first: 1>

>>> Unique.one
<Unique.one: 1>

>>> # name lookup still works
>>> Unique['one']
<Unique.one: 1>

>>> # but value lookups do not
>>> Unique(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: NoAlias enumerations cannot be looked up by value
```

For the second part, decide which you want:

- read and create enums from a file
- create enum in Python and write to a file

Doing both doesn't seem to make a lot of sense.

To create from a file you can use my [JSONEnumMeta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43730306/208880) answer.

To write to a file you can use my [share enums with arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65193248/208880) answer (after adapting the `__init_subclass__` code).

The only thing I'm not certain of is the last point of syntax-checker and auto-completion support.

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Since it's a normal class and the Members default class members, most coding tools should support this out of the box

Comment: Thank you for this answer @EthanFurman . Unfortunately, with this approach i have to use `Unique.first.value` to access the actual value which i don't like at all.

so for now i decided to simply use a module with module-wide variables which can be iterated using the builtin `vars()` on the module and skipping anything starting and ending with an underscore.

I know this could be considered abuse, but of all the solutions i know of, it's the one i like best (at least until i stumble upon new difficulties)