# share enum between c and python

Tags: python, c, enums

I have enum that used for communication between python server and c client.

I want to have the enum just in single file, prefer to use python enum class.

Also I prefer to avoid mixing with runtime parsing of C enum in python.

Comment: @EthanFurman do you understand why it duplicate? the other question is much more complicated in C side, to create bi direction lookup table between string and int, while here need just C enum

Comment: I think it is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65048495/share-enum-between-python-and-arduino as arduino is c based

Answer (score 3):

Optional solution is to have the enum in *.py file, which C file can include and python can import.

The file will look like:

```
#if 0
"""
#endif
typedef enum my_enum{
#if 0
"""
from enum import IntEnum, unique
@unique
class MyEnum(IntEnum):
#endif
    FIRST = 0,
    SECOND = 1,
    THIRD = 2,
#if 0
"""
#endif
}my_enum_e;

#if 0
"""
#endif
```

The idea behind it is that Python ignores all the C preprocessor commands, as they are in Python triple-quoted strings, which is where I put the C only code.

In the other hand, C ignores everything inside #if 0 - where I put the python code.

The disadvantage in this structure is it bit confusing and I didn't find way to make the numbering automatic.

Comment: This has the even bigger disadvantage that in C your enum values are `0`, `1`, and `2`, while in Python it is `(0, )`, `(1, )`, and `(2,)` -- 1-element tuples instead of integers.

Comment: @EthanFurman If you are using Enum indeed you will get tuple. But with IntEnum I got integer

Comment: Of course, you're right.  Thanks for the reminder.