# Suppress C++ comments in pyparsing to load enums correcly

Tags: python, c++, pyparsing

The second answer in this link provides a way to load enums from C++ to python:

[Can python load definitions from a C header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58732872/can-python-load-definitions-from-a-c-header-file/66037988#66037988)

The code works with the given example:

```
sample = """
stuff before
enum hello {
    Zero,
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Five=5,
    Six,
    Ten=10
    };
in the middle
enum blah
    {
    alpha,
    beta,
    gamma = 10 ,
    zeta = 50
    };
at the end
"""
```

However, it does not work for the following, due to the comments inside the enum:

```
sample = """
stuff before
enum hello {
    Zero,  //zero
    One,   //one
    Two,   //two
    Three,  //three
    Five=5,
    Six,
    Ten=10
    };
in the middle
enum blah
    {
    alpha,
    beta,   //beta
    gamma = 10 ,
    zeta = 50
    };
at the end
"""
```

Is there a simple way to suppress these comments in line with the code provided in the link above? I cannot comment on the answer as I lack the reputation.

Comment: What effort did you make to adapt, change, improve code around:
`enumValue = Group(identifier("name") + Optional(EQ + integer("value")))`

Comment: it seems to me, during parsing, a comment would just be another optional piece of code after then enum name and value.

Comment: Why not preprocess the file first?

Answer (score 1):

Import `cppStyleComment` from pyparsing, and than add it to the ignorables for your enum expression:

```
from pyparsing import cppStyleComment
...
enum.ignore(cppStyleComment)
```

This will handle C++ comments anywhere in your expression, not just the end-of-line ones in your example.

(Also, you should add the `[pyparsing]` tag to your question.)