# Cython cpdef enum: how to avoid duplicated implementation in C++ and Python

Tags: c++, enums, cython

Say you have a C++ enum class defined like this:

```cpp
/** my_enum.h **/
#include <iostream>

enum class fruit_t : unsigned char{
  none = 0x0,
  apple = 0x1,
  banana = 0x2
};

void like_fruit(fruit_t f){std::cout << "I prefer fruit number "<< f << std::endl;}
```

**IDEAL WORLD** Now, using the most recent [Cython approach](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#scoped-enumerations), you can define a nice `cpdef` wrapper for the C++ enum class to get a PEP 435-style Python wrapper (standard cythonize and compilation with C++ is used to run this):

```
# my_cython_wrap.pyx
cdef extern from "my_enum.h":
    cpdef enum class fruit_t(unsigned char):
        none = 0x0
        apple = 0x1
        banana = 0x2
    void like_fruit(fruit_t f)

def py_like_fruit(fruit_t f):
    like_fruit(f)
```

This way, you get an automatically translated python `fruit_t` type that can be passed **as-is** to wrapped functions requiring arguments of C++ type `fruit_t`. Basically awesome.

```py
#> python
my_apple = fruit_t['apple']
py_like_fruit(my_apple)
```

**PROBLEM** This only works if the `cdef extern` block is defined in a `.pyx` file. If, on the contrary, we define it in a separate `.pxd` file, we no longer get the nice wrapper. In consequence, the example below fails to compile due to non-existing "fruit_t" type in pythonland:

```
# my_enum.pxd
cdef extern from "my_enum.h":
    cpdef enum class fruit_t(unsigned char):
        none = 0x0
        apple = 0x1
        banana = 0x2
    void like_fruit(fruit_t f)
```

```
# my_cython_wrap.pyx
from my_enum cimport *
def py_like_fruit(fruit_t f):
    like_fruit(f)
```

**WORKAROUND** We can define a different python class to act as "wrapper":

```
# my_cython_wrap.pyx
from my_enum cimport *
from enum import Enum
class py_fruit_t(Enum):
   none=0x0
   apple=0x1
   banana=0x2

def py_like_fruit(py_fruit_t f):
    like_fruit(f.value)
```

So... is there anyway to avoid this duplicated definition (the `fruit_t` and the `py_fruit_t`)?

Comment: This sounds like it should be a bug report more than a stack overflow question

Comment: I would say a bug report *and* an SO question -- others may need a workaround until the issue is fixed.

Comment: @ibarrond: Can you avoid the problem by creating the Enum from the C++ source files ([documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66037988/208880)) ?

Comment: @EthanFurman You're proposing to manually scan the C++ file, extract the enum from there and create an equivalent Python class. I guess it is worth trying out, but the apartent complexity of it makes me shiver.

Comment: @ibarrond: Well, if by "manually" you mean have the code do it -- then yes.  :-)